# Spellcheck for INPUT in UIWebview is stopped working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios7.1

I noticed it worked for sometime then it suddenly stopped working(no red dotted underline).

Can anyone help me to make it work everytime?

Sample code:

```
NSString *h= @"<input type=text spellcheck=\"true\"/>";
[webView loadHTMLString:h baseURL:nil];
```

I am using iOS 7.1.x

--
Manoj

**UPDATE:**

Just realized that it actually doing the spellcheck and suggesting when we tap on the word, but no visible red dotted underline.

[image]